# How to post long url so IE can take it in spring?

Tags: spring, internet-explorer, url

I am trying to POST long url, which is fine with most browsers, but in IE only about 2000 chars in url is allowed. Url has lots of parameters and is send in string. After sending a filled form should appear. Redirect works on most browsers, but IE cuts the url. I tried to use forward instead of redirect thinking it would send my url internaly to bypass the IE restriction, but it doesnt work...

```
@Controller("MyForwardController")
public class MyForwardController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/url-showing-in-browser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test(@RequestParam String myParams) {
    return "forward:/url-i-want-to-get-to?" + myParams;
}
```

A am not even sure how forward works... Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you POST the parameters (like you already seem to do in your request mapping), then there should be no need to append them to the (GET) URL.